# Online Tool For Formatting Scala Code

Tags: scala, format

Is there any online service that format scala code ? I use Sublime Text for editing the .scala files but not sure how to align the periods and parenthesis .

Comment: What is stopping you from learning to format your own `code` with the help of this nice SBT plugin: http://www.scalastyle.org/sbt.html ?

Answer (score 2):

This website seems to be pretty useful: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you need, but maybe you could look at [this plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScalaFormat).